# php update SQL statement not working

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to make a working login page, and I want to keep track of the successful and unsuccessful logins for the user.

I'm trying to do this with an update statement in php:

```
     $updateSQL="UPDATE login SET successfulLogins = IFNULL(successfulLogins, 0) + 1 
     WHERE username ='". $user ."'";
     $updateStmnt=$dbcon->prepare($updateSQL);
     $updateStmnt->execute();
```

Which gives me the error: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

I tried manually entering the update statement in the database using SQL and it worked fine, so the issue is something to do with the php.. I think

Thanks

EDIT: I fixed this problem by closing dbcon earlier in the code, but now I have the same issue with this code:

```
    $isError=true;
    $errorMessage.="Username or password is incorrect<br />";

    $updateSQL="UPDATE login SET unsuccessfulLogins = IFNULL(unsuccessfulLogins, 0) + 1 
    WHERE username ='". $user ."'";
    $updateStmnt=$dbcon->prepare($updateSQL);
    $updateStmnt->execute();
```

I am now getting :

Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Comment: what's the output of `print $updateSQL`?

Comment: How are you instantiating $dbcon? Can you add more info on that?

Comment: try passing in `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` as an option when creating the connection and see if there's any exceptions being thrown and what they are saying.

Comment: Do you have error handling and display enabled? If not, you should start with that.

Comment: If you want to use prepared statements, please use placeholders instead of inserting (random) text directly in your query. For examples see [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. It was simply an issue of not closing $dbcon and $stmnt in the right places... I'm sure if I provided more code anybody could have told me that.

Next time I'll post more of my code. I'm new to this website!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $updateSQL = "UPDATE login SET successfulLogins = IFNULL(successfulLogins, 0) + 1 WHERE username ='". $user ."'";
 // check your function returns
 if( ! $updateStmnt = $dbcon->prepare($updateSQL) ) {
     // check for error information if an error occurred
     die(print_r($dbcon->errorInfo()));
 }
 // second verse, same as the first
 if( ! $updateStmnt->execute() ) {
     die(print_r($updateStmnt->errorInfo()));
 }
```

Basically your `prepare()` has failed for one reason or another and, because you're neither checking your function returns nor feeding PDO the `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` flag, your script just trucks along until it hits a second error and actually dies.